# How do I store latitudes and longitudes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store latitude `39.8162994` and longitude `-98.5576019` as floats but turns out be like `0.00000000000` and `-98.55760192871`, accordingly.

What's the problem? I am using `float(15,11)` as a data type.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to insert the data?

Comment: Hey, Mark! How would I store latitude and longitude like those I pointed with the help of php? What should I set on the table?

Answer (score 6):

You should probably use `DECIMAL(10,7)` in order to be able to store a [longitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude) value with 7 decimal places: `±179.1234567`. The `FLOAT` data type is used to represent approximate numeric data values, where on the other hand you might prefer to store the exact values with the `DECIMAL` data type instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you either use a [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html) type or store it as an integer with a known offset (say `10e-7`).

Use at least as many digits precision as you need to keep:

```
DECIMAL(15,12)
```